# exporting data to excel from my database

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

i need to export my sql-server database to an excel file between day x and day y ( i have a field in my database that contains the date ) . How can i do so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 2005 or 2008 version you can use [Integration Services](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/integration-services.aspx).
[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc952922%28SQL.100%29.aspx) you can find video how to export data to excel with Integration Services.  And [here](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/sqlserver/soa/How-to-import-an-Excel-file-into-SQL-Server-2005-using-Integration-Services/0,339028455,339285948,00.htm) is example how to import from excel.

If you have prior version of MS SQL you can use [Data Transformation Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917688.aspx).

Comment: will data transformation services work also for the newer versions ?

Comment: New versions provide optional support of DTS packages (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500440.aspx), but it is depricated and you can convert (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768544%28SQL.100%29.aspx) DTS packages to Integration Services.

Answer (score -1):

- SO search yields the following question:

[C# export to excel from sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401370/c-export-to-excel-from-sql-server)

- Google search yields the following article:

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1202

Filtering posts by date can be accomplished by for instance a view or a query gettings the desired posts

Search is your friend

EDIT:

- Also, someone posted the same problem on another site

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10102953/export-data-from-sqlserver-to-excel.aspx

Comment: just to let you know,i'm not lazy, i found some ways but thought to ask better.. Thanks!