# Porting data from SQL Server to Excel sheet using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, sql-server-2008

I have to port the data stored in a SQL Server database into an Excel sheet. Can anyone please provide me a suitable link for doing this? I am using ASP.net C#.

Comment: does it have to be done in C# code? there are lot of alternatives like using [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd299421.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# export to excel from sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401370/c-export-to-excel-from-sql-server)

Comment: This must have been asked **at least ten gazillion times** already here..... please **search first** before posting yet again....

Answer (score 0):

Depends what your requirements are and what's available. You can export the data as csv which Excel can open and read or you can use the Microsoft Excel Object Library. Sample for the latter can be found on [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084) and lots of other places

Answer (score 0):

You can divide your problem into two parts:

1. [using C# program/DLL in Excel, see this Stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694422/beginner-tutorials-for-excel-programming-in-c)

They you need to know how to read data from MSSQL using C#
You can search around MSDN, or stackoverflow for additional information
Basically, you need to choose to use a Database Adapter (ODBC, ADO.NET etc...)

2. e.g. [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/f1395b76-86f9-41fb-882d-622332cb7329/)

hope this is helpful enough.

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit on the complexity of the Excel file you want to generate and how much control you need over formatting etc.

In ASP.NET I think it is still not recommended to use Office Interop due to potential deadlock (UI locking issues).

We generally use Aspose.Cells, a commercial product which we have been quite happy with, but it is not free.

If the file is simple (Single Sheet, just data dump) writing out a CSV is usually sufficient.